# Delete everything after date on Atom using Regex

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I have the following dates:

```
2020-09-01,13:23:29.000+0000
2020-07-22,13:13:48.000+0000
2020-01-09,21:58:48.000+0000
```

I wonder how can I just keep the date in atom, the result should be like:

```
2020-09-01
2020-07-22
2020-01-09
```

I tried to find all `^(.*?)\s,.*$` and then replace by `$1` which was not working.

Comment: It does not work because there is not whitespace before the comma. This would work `^(.*?)\s*,.*$` but better use the posted pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Online demo is: [Online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/biWBaN/2)

```
^\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}
```

***Explanation:*** `^\d{4}` checking condition if it starts with 4 digits followed by a non-capturing group of `(-\d{2}){2}` which means a dash followed by 2 digits and this group comes 2 times match that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d/
```

or

```
/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.